# How do I share between applications the auto-generated SpecificRecord POJO by avro-maven-plugin

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm new to Kafka and Avro, I have been reading how Avro provides a nice maven utility `avro-maven-plugin` to generate Avro POJO records, also I understand that using the schema registry is the way to have a centralized place and to share schema evolutions across multiple applications, most consumers.

All the examples that I have been looking at, have the consumer and producer in the same Java application using the same generated `SpecificRecord`, that is fine for examples, however, I'm planning to have multiple consumers with the source code in different repositories.

- How do you maintain and share the auto-generated `SpecificRecord` POJOs?
- Is sharing `SpecificRecord` POJOs a thing or each application should deal with deserialization using only the Avro definition from the schema registry?
- Do you create a Java package dependency or what would be a good practice?